# Why out of three invalidateQueries two works one dont?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am learning to use react-query in my project. I am using the same logic to invalidate the "bookmark" query in multiple mutate functions. It works there but in my handleLogin function it is not refetching the data. On the other hand, the other two invalidate queries work fine.

Here is my code:

```
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const toast = useToast();

    const { mutate: handleLogin } = useMutation(({ emailId, password }: loginUserParams) => loginUser({ emailId, password }), {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries(["categoryList"]);
            queryClient.invalidateQueries(["subsStatus"]);
            queryClient.invalidateQueries("bookmark");
            toast({ title: "User logged", status: "success", duration: 3000, isClosable: true });
            navigate("/");
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
```

I changed `queryClient.invalidateQueries("bookmark");` to `queryClient.refetchQueries("bookmark");` and now it is working but don't know the reason why it didn't worked for `invalidateQueries`

Please guide me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the bookmark query is not in live. Please check once with query monitor and check whether it is in live or not. React-query will trigger a refetch for invalidated queries only when the query is in live.

You can check the queryMonitor by adding  inside your queryClient provider.

like

```js
<QueryClientProvider client = {appQueryClient}>
  <LoadAppHere />
  <ReactQueryDevtools />
</QueryClientProvider>
```